# why switcher in python3 goes through all cases?

Tags: python, python-3.x

what is wrong with code below, switcher goes through all cases
please check let me know the problems thank you

```
def user(name):
    print(name)

def card(i):
    switcher={
        919204184:user('A'),
        1371925194:user('B'),
        2522816213:user('C'),
        39219252185:user('D'),
        249255118211:user('E'),
        18549109194:user('F')}
    return switcher.get(i,user('UNKNOWN'))

card(39219252185)

Result:
A
B
C
D
E
F
UNKNOWN
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Comment: if i use return name instead of print name, result is okay.

Answer (score 1):

When the switcher variable is created it will build the dictionary by evaluating all the values.  If you want to postpone this evaluation, your dictionary should store functions (or lambdas) instead of values.  This will allow your card() function to only execute the user() function that matches the key:

```
def user(name):
    print(f"executed user({name})")
    return name

def card(i):
    switcher={
        919204184:   lambda:user('A'),
        1371925194:  lambda:user('B'),
        2522816213:  lambda:user('C'),
        39219252185: lambda:user('D'),
        249255118211:lambda:user('E'),
        18549109194: lambda:user('F')
        }
    getUser = switcher.get(i,lambda:user('UNKNOWN'))
    return getUser() # only execute the function for the matching key
```

output:

```
print(card(39219252185))

# executed user(D)
# D
```

Note that, if the function calls only vary by the parameters you use, it would be an overkill to store functions as values.  You simply need to store the parameter values and call the function once at the end:

```
def card(i):
    switcher={
        919204184:   'A',
        1371925194:  'B',
        2522816213:  'C',
        39219252185: 'D',
        249255118211:'E',
        18549109194: 'F'
        }
    return user(switcher.get(i,"UNKNOWN"))
```

On the other hand, if your code in each case is more complex and you want a code structure that resembles switch/case statements from other languages, you can define a switch function (generator) that will produce a very similar result:

```
def switch (value):
    def case(*matches):
        return value in matches
    yield case
```

It is meant to be used in a `for case in switch(your_value):` loop (which will only run once).

You can separate the cases in if / elif / else blocks:

```
def card(i):
    for case in switch(i):
        if case   (919204184):
            result = user('A')
        elif case (1371925194):
            result = user('B')
        elif case (2522816213):
            result = user('C')
        elif case (39219252185):
            result = user('D')
        elif case (249255118211):
            result = user('E')
        elif case (18549109194):
            result = user('F')
        else:
            result = user("UNKNOWN")
    return result
```

Or, for more complex cases, you can use if/break structures to allow/prevent continuing in a subsequent block (like C):

```
def card(i):
    for case in switch(i):
        if case (919204184):
            result = user('A')
            break
        if case (1371925194):
            result = user('B')
            break
        if case (2522816213):
            result = user('C')
            break
        if case (39219252185):
            result = user('D')
            break
        if case (249255118211):
            result = user('E')
            break
        if case (18549109194):
            result = user('F')
            break
        result = user("UNKNOWN")
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Your switcher dict has a value that is calling **user()** function each time.

It is the same as you are calling a function and assigning a value to that variable.
Ex:

```
response = user("A") # this function does not return anything so it will just print A.
```

So your switcher dict calling function and assigning that value to key like: 919204184, 1371925194 ...

If you print switcher it will give None to all keys. because the user() function does not return any value.

```
{919204184: None, 1371925194: None, 2522816213: None, 39219252185: None, 249255118211: None, 18549109194: None}
```

If user() function returns value then it will assign that value to dict.

```
def user(name):
    return name

def card(i):
    switcher={
        919204184:user('A'),
        1371925194:user('B'),
        2522816213:user('C'),
        39219252185:user('D'),
        249255118211:user('E'),
        18549109194:user('F')}
    print(switcher)

    return switcher.get(i,user('UNKNOWN'))

print(card(39219252185))
```

Output.

```
{919204184: 'A', 1371925194: 'B', 2522816213: 'C', 39219252185: 'D', 249255118211: 'E', 18549109194: 'F'}
D
```